# Create distictive hovers per word for VSCode extension API?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a text in VSCode like so;

`"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"`

I am working on an extension & want to be able to hover over each word using regex (or anything really) & see distinctive further information about a word in the sentence.

How do I add parameters that enable this?

The snippet (pasted below) [offed by VS code](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/programmatic-language-features#show-hovers) works but it provides the same hover information "Hover information for word" for every word in the sentence

```
vscode.languages.registerHoverProvider('plaintext', {
  provideHover(document, position, token) {
    return {
      contents: ['Hover information for word']
    };
  }
});
```

What I want is for every word in the sentance to have its unique Hover information.

For Instance, hovering my cursor over "fox" may show "wild animal" & hovering over "dog"  will show "domestic animal"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const wordRange = document.getWordRangeAtPosition(position);
const word = document.getText(wordRange);
const map = {
    fox: 'wild',
    dog: 'domestic',
};
return new vscode.Hover(map[word]);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Comment: Could you expand more on how to use that?  For example, how do I attribute the word "fox" to the hover "wild animal"

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since the question is asked, but this may come in handy for others.

The way hover works is you need to register a provider and inside that provider you need to evaluate `document`, `position` and `token` values and return a Hover instance accordingly:

```
languages.registerHoverProvider('javascript', {
  provideHover(document, position, token) {
    // Evaluate document, position and token variables,
    // and show result accordingly.

    if (position.line === 0) {
      return new Hover('I am on line one!');
    }
  }
});
```

If you don't use selective returns, the returned instance will be visible when hovered on any token on any matching document. For the above example, document is any JavaScript file.